# Storing both string and integer in one column together

Tags: sql

I would like to store in a column, a `userID` which goes with this format "`ED25`" Which data type should I use? Additional info to make that possible is welcomed.

Comment: I would use a `varchar` type.  Do you have a reason not to do this?

Comment: Usually it's helpful to tag your question with the DB that you are using plus any additional detail that makes sense (such as version etc).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are using strings, so you should use either a `varchar(n)` or `text`.

If you use PostgreSQL you can use `text`, otherwise you can use `varchar(n)`, where `n` is the maximum possible size of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `varchar(50)`. You can combine ED and # using C# or other language of your choice. In C# you will generate an SQL command like:

```
INSERT INTO yourtablename(ED) VALUES ('ED"+your_int.ToString()+"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a numeric data type like `bigint`.

So, I suggest you to use a mixed mode of `varbinary` and `bigint` like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(varbinary,'ED25'))
```

Result:

```
1162097205
```

And for decoding it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(varbinary, 1162097205))
```

Comment: Why would you use an integer value, when you would need to convert every time you search.  Surely the varchar field with an index should allow the dbms to do what it needs to do best?

Comment: I thought OP knows about `varchar` types and  needs a numeric type, So I suggest this ;).

Comment: There may then be a case for a split key, VARCHAR(2)+BIGINT